# Writing Plugins for Linux in Flutter documentation/tutorial (Trying to write Desktop Camera Plugin)

Tags: linux, windows, flutter, flutter-desktop

I am trying to create Flutter desktop application that can access webcam on desktop (Windows/Linux). It seems like there is no Flutter plugin that support camera for desktop.
Is there any documentation or tutorial about how to write Plugins for Linux/Windows in Flutter?

Answer (score 2):

While the main Flutter documentation on plugins doesn't yet cover writing desktop plugins (since desktop support is still in alpha) there is an Flutter desktop codelab that includes [a section on writing plugins](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-github-graphql-client/index.html#5)

The plugin APIs themselves also have header documentation if you're looking for more detailed information about using the APIs.

(A camera plugin in particular will for Linux and Windows will run into the problem that there isn't yet `Texture` support for those platforms, so there's no good way to show the live camera view inline; you'd have to do something like display it in another window for now. However, there is work in progress at the time of this answer to provide preliminary support for `Texture` on both platforms.)

Comment: Thanks @smorgan! Do you know when will be a stable release Flutter desktop?

Comment: Can HTML element used as live camera view?